# Remapping apple keyboard modifier keys with xkbOptions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, apple

I want to remap my apple keyboard's keys so that just to the right of the spacebar I have a key that acts as Ctrl and to the left of the spacebar I want the first button to acts as alt/meta and the next one as 'winkey'.

I had done this earlier by having this in my xkbOptions:

```
xkbOptions = "altwin:left_meta_win,ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl"
```

I haven't used my apple wireless keyboard in some time, and now when I tried this remapping, the "ctrl:swap_rwin_rctrl" works as I want it: it swaps the right control with 'right win key', but the "altwin:left_meta_win" doesn't work.

BTW, I'm using NixOS, the above snippet is from my configuration.nix file.
I am unable to find the list of possible remap options for xkbOptions online...